# How To Return A Graceful Error When Auth Fails For a Custom Web Service

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a web service up and running with `<cflogin>` used for authentication and everything works as expected when you provide a **valid** username/password. The problem I have is that if **authentication fails** on the `<cfinvoke>` side (client) I get a huge error dump of data rather than a graceful error message back from the service (ie: "Bad Username and/or Password. Contact your administrator").

I'm using the cflogin method to secure the web service as described here: [help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13a13-7fe0.html](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13a13-7fe0.html)

Here is a snip of the CFDUMP (DUMP.Diagnostics) I get back when I provide a bad username/and-or/password:

```
Cannot perform web service invocation service_name. The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is:<br> <pre>AxisFault faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP faultSubcode: faultString: (401)Unauthorized faultActor: faultNode: faultDetail: {}:return code: 401 &lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd&quot;&gt; &lt;html xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;&gt; &lt;head&gt; &lt;title&gt;IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 401.5 - Unauthorized&lt;/title&gt; &lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt; &lt;!-- body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;background:#CBE1EF;} code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} .config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 40px;} ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} .summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} legend... ''</pre> <br>The error occurred on line 25.
```

I suspect it has something to do with the snippet below (from the article above) but trying to return a string causes an "premature end of file" error:

```
<cfif not isAuthorized>
    <!--- If the user does not pass a user name/password, return a 401 error.  
    The browser then prompts the user for a user name/password. ---> 
    <cfheader statuscode="401">
    <cfheader name="WWW-Authenticate" value="Basic realm=""Test"""> 
    <cfabort> 
</cfif>
```

Comment: Okay, you are trying to return error. Any problems with your solution? What's your question, exactly?

Comment: The problem is I can't return a custom/graceful error, when connection fails on the request (client) side I get a dump back from the CF server with the error above rather than being able to provide a simple text string back saying something like "Bad Username/Password".